# Which are the episodes in Star Trek series with courtroom drama?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

I like to watch courtroom dramas. I also like science fiction. Combining my 2 likes, I would like to know which are the episodes in Star Trek series with courtroom drama.

Comment: I'd say this is legit. It's a finite list for a particular series.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few that at least factor in "legal proceedings" in some form:

ST: TOS - *Court Martial* [from @Bob]

> Kirk draws a court martial in the negligent death of a crewman.

ST: TOS - *The Squire of Gothos*

> Trelane was now a judge determined to sentence Kirk for the crimes of treason against a superior authority, conspiracy, and the attempt to foment insurrection

ST: TOS - *Wolf in the Fold*

> Kirk and the Enterprise Computer become detectives after Scotty is accused of murdering women on a pleasure planet.

ST: TOS - *The Menagerie* [from @Sarriesfan]

> Spock kidnaps the crippled Capt. Pike, hijacks the Enterprise and then surrenders for court martial.

ST: Animated - *The Magicks of Megas-Tu*

> Lucien explains that some of the people of Megas-Tu did once visit Earth, and that most of the witches and magical beings of Earth lore were actually magicians from his homeworld. The crew's use of magic, however, attracts the attention of other Megans, and Lucien is unexpectedly apprehended. It turns out that Lucien is the only Megan to love Earthlings, and that other Megans were driven from Earth in 1691 during the Salem witch trials. A Megan judge puts humanity on trial for their crass and “let's hang them witches” attitudes of centuries in the past. As such, the Megans recreate a 1691 witch tribunal and put humanity and Lucien on trial

ST: TNG - *Encounter at Farpoint*

> On the maiden mission of the U.S.S. Enterprise (NCC-1701-D), an omnipotent being known as Q challenges the crew to discover the secret of a mysterious base in an advanced and civilized fashion.

ST: TNG - *The Drumhead*

> An overzealous Starfleet admiral begins a witch-hunt aboard the Enterprise, determined to find a conspiracy, and eventually accusing Captain Picard of treason.

ST: TNG - *Sins of the Father*

> A Klingon commander comes aboard the Enterprise in an officer exchange program initiated by Starfleet, much to the chagrin of the crew.

ST: TNG - *The First Duty*

> Wesley Crusher's team has an accident at Starfleet Aacademy. Picard offers to help a Starfleet investigation as to what happened, and begins to suspect they are hiding something.

ST: TNG - *The Measure of a Man* [from @Bob]

> When Data resigns his commission rather than be dismantled for examination by an inadequately skilled scientist, a formal hearing is convened to determine whether Data is considered property without rights or is a sentient being.

ST: TNG - *Devil's Due* [from @OneWholeBurrito]

> Ardra demands a planet honor a contract concluded 1,000 years ago.. Picard is told she is known by many names in various systems, all frightening and almost almighty, but he refuses to believe she's the planet's version of the Devil, and decides to challenge her legal claim.

ST: DS9 - *Rules of Engagement*

> When Worf destroys a civilian shuttle during an engagement with the Klingons, an extradition hearing is held to see if he must face charges.

ST: DS9 - *Dax*

> Jadzia Dax is accused of a murder her previous host, Curzon, supposedly committed.

ST: DS9 - *Inquisition*

> Dr. Bashir's plans to attend a medical conference at a breezy resort are canceled when Starfleet Intelligence boards DS9, suspecting the doctor of treason.

ST: DS9 - *Tribunal* [from @Bob and comments]

> Chief O'Brien goes through the horrific Cardassian judicial system when he is charged for an unknown crime.

ST: VOY - *Author, Author*

> The Doctor completes work on a holonovel that depicts the crew of Voyager in rather unflattering roles as they abuse and scorn the Emergency Medical Hologram. When the holonovel is published without his permission, the issue of The Doctor's legal rights is brought into question. Seven reconnects with her aunt.

ST: VOY - *Ex Post Facto*

> The Baneans wrongfully convict Tom Paris of murder. Technology plus the Banean physiology can access someone's last experiences before death and the evidence shows Tom killing a jealous husband. His sentence is to re-live his crimes through his victim's eyes every 14 hours for life.

ST: VOY - *Random Thoughts*

> Voyager visits a planet with a telepathic races that outlaws negative thoughts. When B'Elanna is charged with releasing an angry thought into the society and condemned to a dangerous neurological procedure, Tuvok uncovers a black market dealing in violent thoughts.

ST: VOY - *Distant Origin* [from @Derek]

> The scientist is thrilled to be able to prove his Distant Origin theory (that his Voth race originated elsewhere in the galaxy), but the rulers of his society place him on trial for heresy against the doctrinal teachings of their heritage, the central tenet being that they originated in the Delta Quadrant. The outcome of that trial threatens the Voyager crew as well.

ST: VOY - *Death Wish* [from @Bob]

> The crew accidentally releases a member of the Q Continuum who has been imprisoned within it for over 300 years to prevent him from committing suicide. He then requests asylum on the ship, which leaves Captain Janeway to decide whether he should go back into confinement or whether to grant his request for asylum, which would give him the opportunity to end his life.

ST: E - *Judgement*

> After Enterprise lends aid to a group of accused rebels, Captain Archer faces a tribunal and charges of conspiring against the Klingon Empire

*Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*

> Gorkon's chief of staff, General Chang, puts Kirk and McCoy on trial for his [Gorkon's] assassination.

Comment: I think he's trying to only list episodes that weren't already mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @Ixrec - which is a bad idea, because now it's the top rated answer and makes no sense without first reading answers that are lower down the page...

Comment: @Jules Answer updated to include other [attributed] answers.

Comment: ST:TNG S1E09 Justice; where Wesley is sentenced to death because he jumped on a greenhouse?

Comment: ST:TNG S5E17 The Outcast has a court scene, where Soren is sentenced to psychotectic treatment.

Answer (score 10):

"The Measure of a Man," "Court Martial," the episode where Chief O'Brien is on trial by Cardassians, and "Death Wish" are the ones I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Upvoted. However, would you mind indicating which season and which star trek series?

Comment: Bob, I appreciate the good answer.

Comment: "The Measure of a Man" is second-season of TNG. "Court Martial" is TOS, Chief episode is DS9, and the last one is Voyager. I'm not sure of the seasons for those three. Kes is in the Voyager episode, so I'm guessing Season 3

Comment: @user91579631 The Chief O'Brien episode is called Tribunal. It's the 25th episode of season 2 of DS9.

Comment: @user91579631 The 7th episode of season 1 of DS9 probably qualifies too. Jadzia Dax has to answer for some sins of a former host of the Dax symbiont. The episode is called Dax.

Comment: @ Duane Dibbley, you can put that as an answer. Easier for reference. I will upvote it.

Comment: @user91579631 I'm a bit reluctant, as it's only one episode, and the fact that someone already raised the question of the on-topicness of this.

Comment: I think there were three TOS episodes that featured some form of courtroom drama: *The Menagerie* (Spock on trial for commandeering the Enterprise); *Court Martial* (Kirk is accused of criminal negligence); *Wolf in the Fold* (Scotty tried for murder). *Squire of Gothos* and *The Space Seed* also showed some form of legal proceeding but it wasn't central to the plot.

Comment: "...on trial by Cardassians" - did anyone else go to a scary visual place?

Comment: @Baard Kopperud
I used to get them confused, but now I just remember that one lot are creepy reptilians with an unjustified sense of importance and the others invaded Bajor.

Answer (score 5):

Star Trek: Voyager S3E23 [Distant Origin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Distant_Origin_(episode)) involves a Voth scientist who is accused of heresy against the Voth Doctrine and goes before their Ministry to face trial.

Answer (score 3):

Portions of the original pilot episode of TOS 'The Cage' were later reused in the 2 part episode [The Menagerie](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Menagerie,_Part_I), which features to the end of part 1 a Court Martial for Spock.

Answer (score 2):

Also be sure to check out "Devil's Due" s4e13 of TNG. Picard puts the Devil on trial.